# How to use the FormFactory outside of Controller class

Tags: java, playframework, dependency-injection, mockito, guice

I am trying to write some simple unit tests for my templates. The problem is that the templates are using the helper.Form classes.

```
@helper.form(action = routes.SecurityController.login()) {
    @helper.inputText(loginForm("email"))
    @helper.inputPassword(loginForm("password"))
}
```

Which are throwing null pointer exceptions because I'm mocking the form.
Here's (part of) my test class:

```
@Mock
protected Form<User> userForm;

@Test
public void testLoginPage() {
    Content html = views.html.login.render(userForm);
    assertTrue(html.body().contains("Login to your Account"));
}
```

Instead of mocking all of the calls to the already mocked form, I'd like to just be able to create the empty form similar to how it's done in the controller

```
@inject
private FormFactory formFactory;

public Result showLoginPage() {
    return ok(views.html.login.render(formFactory.form(User.class));
}
```

But I cannot for the life of me, inject the FormFactory into my test classes. Every solution I've tried has failed, including:

```
FormFactory formFactory = new GuiceInjectorBuilder().injector().instanceOf(FormFactory.class);
```

The documentation shows how I can do this by starting a fakeApplication, similar to [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaTest#Unit-testing-controllers) but that's complete overkill for just testing the content of a template. Is what I'm trying to do possible? I feel like this is a very simple concept, yet it's been incredibly difficult to find a solution to.

I am using **Play Framework 2.5.6**